# Rails refactor code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, refactoring

I had a code below:

```
  @brand = Brand.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @brand.nil?
    flash[:error] = Flash.record_not_found
    redirect_to admin_brands_path
  end
```

And another change to below:

```
@brand = Brand.find_by_id(params[:id])
return(flash[:error] = Flash.record_not_found and redirect_to admin_brands_path) if @brand.nil?
```

Which code do you think is more efficient and explain?
and when you have another suggest you can share too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My Question is: in Rails MiniTest: I want to test a controller that get `user_phone` param value from `HTTP X Header`. how can I sent this param in `my video_controller_test.rb` file. like in my `video_controller.rb` get values as:
`user_phone = request.env['HTTP_X_MSISDN'].to_s`

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it like this:

```
def action
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to admin_brands_path, flash: {error: Flash.record_not_found}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel the upper one code is better as it is easy to understand and very clean, however you can write it as following too

```
unless @brand = Brand.find_by_id(params[:id])
  flash[:error] = Flash.record_not_found
  redirect_to admin_brands_path
end
```

Answer (score -1):

First option is definately *much better* - no doubt about it. It is readable, not too much logic inside and it does only what controllers are supposed to do. Having the least lines of code really isn't a good metric.

As far as refactoring goes, I would leave it just the way it is. Maybe change #find_by_id to #find, but that's it.

Comment: If you just change find_by_id to find, an error will occur. Check out my answer on how to handle it.